# Spring Security configuration on URL and users

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-boot

I want two kinds of requests in my REST server:
Those who has the path "/freerest/" anyone can request, others will need authentication.

This is my code:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}

@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

  @Override
  public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
  }

  @Bean
  UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {

      @Override
      public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserAccount account = userAccountRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if(account != null) {
            return new User(account.getEmail(), account.getPassword(), true, true, true, true,
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"));
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("could not find the user '"
                  + email + "'");
        }
      }

    };
  }
}

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/freerest/**").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("USER");
  }
}
```

In my mind after hasAnyAuthority("USER"), should have a .permitAll(). But dont.

So, the freerest path works fine, but if I try some user, which is on my database, or the default Spring's user I get 403.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You have added an `and()` inbetween the antMatch ans any Request. I think that is the problem.

And also add the correct authenticating realm followed by an `and()` as shown below. *here I use the HTTP Basic Authentication for restful*

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        ......
        ......
        ......

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/freerest/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("USER")
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }

        ......
        ......
        ......

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works when I request with my user, is no more returning 403. But if I request with no basic auth its returning 200 too.
Like, if I request localhost:8080/banana without basic auth should return 401 or 403...